# Substring of a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a variable defined in a batch file as follows

```
set "SERVERNAME=VKR\SQL2012"
```

I need to extract VKR from this. Is there a way I could do this?

I tried this

```
set "value=%SERVERNAME:*\=%"
echo %value%
```

which returned SQL2012 but not VKR

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727231/how-to-extract-a-substring-on-batch-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FOR /F`, when you don't know how the length of the first part.
The delimiter will split the string at the `\` character

```
set "SERVERNAME=VKR\SQL2012"
for /F "tokens=1 delims=\" %%F in ("%SERVERNAME%") do set "pre=%%F"
echo %pre%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to take the first three characters (assuming it's a fixed length):

```
set "SERVERNAME=VKR\SQL2012"
set "value=%SERVERNAME:~0,3%"
echo %value%
```

See: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is no `%var:string*=%`. But there is a better way: Splitting the string:

```
set "SERVERNAME=VKR\SQL2012"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%a in ("%servername%") do echo -%%a- -%%b-
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
set "SERVERNAME=VKR\SQL2012"
set "value=%SERVERNAME:\=" & rem "%"
echo %value%
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is happening here, please??

Comment: @DanielLuz: You may run this code with `echo on` to see exactly what is executed. You may see another example of this technique at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745570/set-a-command-expands-with-a-comma-for-more-than-one-var-only-set-does-not/36748769#36748769).

Comment: I looked at the other example and I've kinda understood what it did... But HOW does it happens? Is there any documentation about it? The string substituition is acting like a splitter? Why? And how the splitted tokens went to the final "%" sign? Is it something with the "&" command? (Sorry about all these questions, but this really triggered me =/)

Comment: @DanielLuz: There is nothing new here: a `%variable%` expansion is done _before_ the resulting line is parsed for special characters, like `&<|>`. Try: `set "test=echo one & echo two"` followed by `%test%`

Comment: Well, that was new to me! Understood what happened and how, just need to practice and test it for a while. Thank you so much, sir! =D

Comment: @DanielLuz: Well, if you liked this method, you'll get more fun at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)