# set /A command expands with a comma for more than one var, only set does not

Tags: batch-file

```
(set /a "m1=1,m2=2")
for /f %%c in ("%m1%%m2%") do echo %%c
pause
```

The brackets else where than due to the for command are used in cases, a space key should have been added.
The echo of the for command, is 12. I used the number characters to face the set /A command with decimal Expression.
When i try the same procedure only with a set for a Shell, may also be named m1 it is just possible without comma seperation.
With set command the m1 Expression would be 1 m2 2 and not two values like with a set /A SET.
Is there a way to use set only once and not only with the set /A?

Comment: No, a normal `SET` does not support more than one variable assignment. Only `SET /A` supports more than one variable assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers and comments already indicated, there is no way to *directly* do this in one command, but via a procedure. The method below is the simplest one:

```
@echo off

rem Define the several values
set "vars=m1=1,m2=2"

rem Do it:
set "%vars:,=" & set "%"

echo m1=%m1%
echo m2=%m2%
```

You may remove the `@echo off` command and execute this program to see what exactly is executed...

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question you want something like:

```
set x=1,y=2
```

and as a result to have two variables (like `set /a`). The answer is no.
Though you can iterate trough expressions with plain for :

```
@echo off

for %%a in (
 "x=1" "a=5"
 "y=2" "b=6"
 "z=3" "c=7"
) do set "%%~a"

echo %x% %y% %z% %a% %b% %c%
```

Mind that the quotes around the items are mandatory because `=` is a delimiter. You can put everything on line and to use as separators `,` ,`;` ,`<space>`
May be with a lot of variables this can save you from some writing...?

this can be rewritten like this:

```
@echo off
set "vars=x=1,y=2,z=3,a=5,b=6,c=7"
for %%a in ("%vars:,=","%") do set "%%~a"

echo %x% %y% %z% %a% %b% %c%
```

And thus you'll need to change only the `vars` value.

Comment: This will not work if any of the values contain wildcards `*` or `?`

Comment: @dbenham  - aah yes.Good to be noted.

Comment: The above solutions for my question are fullfiled. Many Thanks. The replacement of strings or the use of the for loop variant, was not supported in my Knowledge. For the jump in my Manual for Batch menues it is very usefull.